# Question about app info card view accompanying ios mobile app video ads

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, ads, cardview

This is an iOS app, not a web.

Video ads on various advertising platforms come with information in the form of a card, such as an attached image.

The layout is the same, and pressing the download button installs the app right away without having to go to the store.

I want to implement a card view like this.

Is it correct to implement one yourself? Doesn't the same form of uiview and operation officially support? Information is required.

[image]
Admob VideoAd

[image]
AppLovin VideoAd

If you implement it yourself,

you cannot install it immediately by clicking the download button, and you have no choice but to go to the store.

Is there any good way?